# Retrieving HTML Table Values

Tags: javascript, html, input, html-table

I created a table and borrowed a javascript function from http://www.fourfront.us/blog/store-html-table-data-to-javascript-array to retrieve the contents of the table the way I wanted to. It almost works, but for some reason I cannot access the value that the user inputs.
I have made a JS fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/danielmdavies/4mu80x2L/1/ 
The code is also posted below. If I use `"time_cutoff": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').html()` instead of `"time_cutoff": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').val(),` I get the html code that is correct I believe.

This is the relevant html code:

```
<table id="cycler_table">
    <tr>
        <th>Cycle Step</th>
        <th>Mode</th>
        <th>Time Cutoff</th>
        <th>Voltage Cutoff</th>
        <th>Current Cuttoff</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <select name='cyc_mode1'>
                <option value='galvanostatic'>Galvanostatic</option>
                <option value='Potentiostatic'>Potentiostatic</option>
                <option name='rest'>Rest</option>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='time_cutoff1' value='10'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='voltage_cutoff1' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='current_cutoff1' value='0'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>
            <select name='cyc_mode2'>
                <option value='galvanostatic'>Galvanostatic</option>
                <option value='Potentiostatic'>Potentiostatic</option>
                <option name='rest'>Rest</option>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='time_cutoff2' value='10'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='voltage_cutoff2' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='current_cutoff2' value='0'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
            <select name='cyc_mode3'>
                <option value='galvanostatic'>Galvanostatic</option>
                <option value='Potentiostatic'>Potentiostatic</option>
                <option name='rest'>Rest</option>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='time_cutoff3' value='10'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='voltage_cutoff3' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='current_cutoff3' value='0'>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>
            <select name='cyc_mode4'>
                <option value='galvanostatic'>Galvanostatic</option>
                <option value='Potentiostatic'>Potentiostatic</option>
                <option name='rest'>Rest</option>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='time_cutoff4' value='10'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='voltage_cutoff4' value='0'>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type='text' name='current_cutoff4' value='0'>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<textarea id="tbTableValuesArray" name="tblValuesArray" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
<p id="cyc_confirm">Waiting for Properties to be Confirmed
    <button onclick="storeAndShowTableValues()">Send the Setup</button>
```

And the Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("ready!");
    storeAndShowTableValues();
});


function storeAndShowTableValues() {
    var TableData;
    TableData = storeTblValues();
    $('#tbTableValuesArray').val('TableData = \n' + print_r(TableData));
}

function storeTblValues() {
    var TableData = new Array();

    $('#cycler_table tr').each(function (row, tr) {
        TableData[row] = {
            "cyc_mode": $(tr).find('td').eq(1).val(),
            "time_cutoff": $(tr).find('td:eq(2)').val(),
            "voltage_cutoff": $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').val(),
            "current_cutoff": $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').val()
        }
    });
    TableData.shift(); // first row will be empty - so remove
    return TableData;
}

function convertArrayToJSON() {
    var TableData;
    TableData = $.toJSON(storeTblValues());
    $('#tbConvertToJSON').val('JSON array: \n\n' + TableData.replace(/},/g, "},\n"));


}

function print_r(arr, level) {
    var dumped_text = "";
    if (!level) level = 0;

    //The padding given at the beginning of the line.
    var level_padding = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < level + 1; j++) level_padding += "    ";

    if (typeof (arr) == 'object') { //Array/Hashes/Objects 
        for (var item in arr) {
            var value = arr[item];

            if (typeof (value) == 'object') { //If it is an array,
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' \n";
                dumped_text += print_r(value, level + 1);
            } else {
                dumped_text += level_padding + "'" + item + "' => \"" + value + "\"\n";
            }
        }
    } else { //Stings/Chars/Numbers etc.
        dumped_text = "===>" + arr + "<===(" + typeof (arr) + ")";
    }
    return dumped_text;
}
```

This is probably super easy but for whatever reason I can't work out how to make it give me the values.
Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Your problem is that you are finding the `td` and trying to get `.val` from that instead of getting the `input` (or `select`) inside that `td`.

Comment: @MattBurland is right, here's an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4mu80x2L/3/

Comment: @MattBurland thank you so much. I would upvote both comment and answer but I don't have the reputation :(

Comment: Also note that for a function called `storeAndShowTableValues` it actually just throws away the value of `TableData` because it's scoped to just that function.

Comment: @MattBurland thanks, just hacking around right now. I'll be careful of that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to get the values:

```
TableData[row] = {
    "cyc_mode": $(tr).find('select').val(),
    "time_cutoff": $(tr).find('input:eq(0)').val(),
    "voltage_cutoff": $(tr).find('input:eq(1)').val(),
    "current_cutoff": $(tr).find('input:eq(2)').val()
};
```

You need to find the actual `input` and `select` elements to get their values.

Or better:

```
var elem = $(tr);
TableData[row] = {
    "cyc_mode": elem.find('select').val(),
    "time_cutoff": elem.find('input:eq(0)').val(),
    "voltage_cutoff": elem.find('input:eq(1)').val(),
    "current_cutoff": elem.find('input:eq(2)').val()
};
```

Which avoids recreating the jquery object four times.